# Excluding UVs from tiling textures?

Tags: texturing

So I have some shader setups on some bottles where the inside gets a different texture to the outside but it's all one glass shader. How would I go about excluding the UVs of say the inside of the bottle when I want to use tiling textures for the outside of the bottle? I ask because I know of no way to exclude the UVs of particular faces from a UV channel aside from moving them outside of UV space.

Comment: You can use a black and white mask image to mix textures or shaders if you want to use only one material.

Comment: Hi. Can make another UV map and place the unwanted part at a specific position. So that you can test it.

Comment: The mask is a good idea, don't see why I can't do some quick and dirty painting over the textures it's just another step I was wondering if I had to do :p

Also Lemon I have multiple UV maps it's just that all of the UVs once unwrapped can't seem to be deleted from a UV map?

Comment: @JamesF, yes they cant be deleted, but you can test their locations: put some above 0.5 and the others below. Then test it in your shader to drive what is tile or not.

Comment: oh, and of course: an object can have several materials